# Displaying Different Pictures For Different Form Results

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-sites

I have a form in google sites as two text fields. I don't know how to actually retrieve the data that is submitted. Is there a way to display a different image on the web page when a specific answer to the form is submitted?

Here's what I have now:

```
<form action="Interactive Map">
Start Room: <input name="StartRoom" type="text" value="" />
End Room: <input name="EndRoom" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an array of images
After the form is submitted you can use random for the index of the array images

Sample Code

```
var arrayImglocation = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg'];
var rand = arrayImglocation[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayImglocation.length)];
```

Comment: is there a way to pick a specific image for a specific response (ie. 206 and 113 are submitted, so cat.png is displayed)?